# Change Maven Archetype after a project is created in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, maven-archetype

I've created a Maven project with `maven-archetype-quickstart`.

I've started coding and now I want to change the archetype to `maven-archetype-webapp` in order to make it a dynamic web project.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Archetypes are just used to create a project (ie initialize configuration, source folders, ...) and are not used after that. So if you want to change your project nature you've to do it "by hand".

It seems that in your case, you just have to change in pom.xml, the package type to war and to proceed a "Maven update project" in your IDE so maven plugin will update configuration.

Comment: Perfect Answer!

Answer (score 3):

I recently googled and got stumbled upon this post. I have got a way to generate the `web.xml` and the directory structure for a web application using **Eclipse IDE**. Before I share that, let's clarify the Eclipse I am using (this feature may not be there in case you are using any older version).

[image]

I assume you created the `Maven Project` with `maven-archetype-quickstart` as posted by OP. It is basically a `jar` application. We want to change this to a `web` application. Here is the process:

1. Right-click the project > Properties > Project Facets
2. Select `Convert to faceted form...`
3. Tic the `Dynamic Web Module` and `Java` boxes. You may want to select the version you need, make sure these are compatible. I selected version `3.0` for `Dynamic Web Module` (the servlet spec) and `Java 1.8`.

[image]

4. Now click `Apply and Close`. This will generate many things in your project.
5. Now switch to `Web perspective` if you're not already in. You can do that by following:
   Window > Perspective > Open Perspective > Other > Web
6. Now you will be able to see what changes we made to project structure in step 4. It has created the directory structure required for web applications. But still `web.xml` file is not yet generated. We will do it next.
7. Right-click on `Deployment Descriptor : <your project name>` > Generate Deployment Descriptor Stub. It will generate the `web.xml` file.

[image]

8. Finally change the packaging in `pom.xml` from jar to war:`<packaging>war</packaging>`
9. Now you are ready to go. Since I was working with `spring-boot` and it requires the `webapp` folder instead of `WebContent`, I manually renamed it and moved it inside `src\main` and then added the `webapp` as a `source folder`.

So basically, we have to do this all manually. I just made Eclipse do little bit of work here.